# Css and javascript files will not refresh on my subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm storing some of my websites css and javascript files in a subdomain.

One of the files is called `xxx.example.com/file.css`, also visible at `example.com/xxx/file.css`.

After I update the file, **and clear my cache**, `example.com/xxx/file.css` is updated with the new code.

However, `xxx.example.com/file.css` keeps the old code.

How can I make the subdomain file update?

Edit: I'm using Apache, cPanel and PHP 4. This could be part of the problem

Comment: You can attach a version to each of your scripts with your server-side language; when new css is uploaded change the version and it should work (or change the css file name)

Comment: Make sure your path should correct and refresh your page using (ctrl+F5)

Comment: PHP 4? That's old isn't it.

Comment: Your server software has nothing to do with overactive caching. Usually ctrl-F5 should do the trick, barring special situations with iframes and/or XHR requests.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I've clearly stated that I have cleared my cache multiple times and even used other browsers and the problem still occurs

Comment: Then you have a different problem, for example uploading to the wrong place. What you describe simply cannot be a serverside problem, clearing clientside cache logically **always** overrides that.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes If I rename the css file and then change the html file to reflect that change the new code is loaded on the subdomain, but then when I update the css file it stops working again